# docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for hyperledger/composer-playground

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am installing the hyperledger composer on azure VM with ubuntu 16.04 OS.
I tried everything possible and am still getting the below error.

Should have started pulling the image but looks like that is not happening.

Could you please help?

---

hyperledger@hyperledger:~/hyperledger_composer$ docker run --name composer-playground --publish 8080:8080 hyperledger/composer-playground

Unable to find image 'hyperledger/composer-playground:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for hyperledger/composer-playground, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

---

Comment: Do you have a link to the repo in docker hub?

Answer (score 2):

Hyperledger Composer is end of life now, all the composer docker images have been deleted. The source code is still available at https://github.com/hyperledger/composer

Comment: Thank you, David! Does that mean, the component called composer is completely removed and we dont have a way that was there earlier with this to build a quick POC?

Comment: Its just that any new updation or changes won't happen but you can still use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm to setup hyperledger composer. Using this link: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/development-tools